# can we call interface method in my domain in domain driven design c# code first mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, code-first

I have this structure in my sub context in my DDD (Sub domain).

[image]

Now I want to use my interfaces in my domain. For example, here is my news Entity:

```
 public  class News
 {
     public Guid Id { set; get; }
     public string Subject { set; get; }
     public string Content { set; get; }
     public DateTime SubmitDatetime { set; get; }
     public DateTime ModifiedDateTime { set; get; }
     public string PublisherName { set; get; }
     public string PictureAddress { set; get; }
     public string TypeOfNews { set; get; }//etelaeie ya khabar
     public HttpPostedFile ImageFile { get; set; } 
 }
```

Suppose I want to add, for example, a news item to my database. My main question is how can I add a news item to my database? Should I call my repository inside the news class and create a method inside the news class to do that?

Comment: There are like 5 unrelated questions embedded in this. Can you try to ask one, more specific question and formulate it with more care?

Comment: @AluanHaddad of course .I did that

Comment: That is a bit better. I am confused, however, as you have written that you _"want to use my interfaces in my domain .for example here is my news Entity :"_, but then what follows is a representation of your entity as a `class`, not an `interface`. Also, be aware that an EF module is not a domain model.

Comment: @AluanHaddad So you mean my entity should be interface ?

Comment: No, but it could be. I mean your statement is confusing.

Comment: @AluanHaddad My main question is how can i add a news to my database ?Should i call my repository inside news class and create a method inside news class to do that ?

Comment: @AluanHaddad of course i did that.

Comment: Your `News` class is the entity model NOT domain model. And no you should not call the Repository from the entity model. Google unit of work pattern in DDD. Domain models are very different from entity model.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Your use of the word "entity" is confusing here. The OP never mentioned Entity Framework. And even then, you can perfectly define EF mappings directly on your domain entities.

Comment: @CodingYoshi But granted, that domain entity is anemic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the Application Service (in `CMSManagement.Application` project) is the one that will

- create a `News`
- call the Repository to add the `News` to it
- conclude the business transaction, effectively persisting the `News` to the DB (often by means of a Unit of Work)